# Контрол-контейнер, хранящий несколько картинок

Tags: winforms

Пипл, нужен ваш хелп.  Кто-нибудь может мне сказать, как называется контрол, в Windows Forms, в который можно положить несколько картинок, к примеру, расположить их в нужной позиции, и чтобы был скролл. Нужно примерно следующее:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

ListView со свойством View = LargeIcon.